# Looking for a simple automated way or program to reformat a list of proxies

Tags: windows-10, proxy, automation, text-editing, text-formatting

I have a long list of SOCKS5 proxies that I want to import into another program. Currently the way I have them formatted is:

> (Socks5)serveraddress:port:username:password

The program I'm importing them into requires the following format to do it automatically:

> (socks5)://[username:password]@serveraddress:port

Edit: I don't know any programming language. If I did I imagine it would be easier to figure out myself.

What tool or automated process could I use to do this quickly without having to manually edit every line in my list?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know any programming languages? Regex?

Comment: @Gantendo Unfortunately, I don't. I've picked up the basics of a few over the years and then forgotten what I know pretty quickly from disuse. I'm hoping there's a program or a few lines of Batch code I could use for this or something. Thanks for the reply.